# Searching for substring in a Binary Search Tree of strings - C++

Tags: c++, string, search, binary-tree

I've inserted a string of Dates into my Binary search tree. Now when the user inputs a year, I would like to check if this year exists in my dates in the BST and if so, I perform some operations. The problem is my searchTree method for my BST returns a bool so I'm not sure how I can search for a substring in my BST or if it is even possible. 
I search for a substring because I do not need the day, or the month. I simply need to check whether this year exists in my BST. Some advice?

What I've done so far:

```
    Bst<string> dateStrings;
    multimap<Date, float> mapOption2;

    for(int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        stringstream converter;
        string convertedDate;

        converter << windlog[i].d;

        converter >> convertedDate;
        //cout << "After conversion: " << convertedDate << endl;

        dateStrings.insertNodeRecursive(convertedDate);
        mapOption2.insert(make_pair(windlog[i].d, windlog[i].temp.GetTemperature()));

    }

if(dateStrings.searchTreeRecursive(strcmp)) // This is where I am stuck.
```

My search tree method returns a boolean value, and it's parameter is just meant to be a variable of any type, in this case it should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pair of int and string where int will be your year number and string will be your date string. Once you create each pair, insert the complete pair into your BST. So, now when ever a year comes as a input to your function, you can find if that year is present in your BST which contains each node as a pair.

Comment: So my pairs should be something like this for example? 2014, 16/4/2014? How can I create pairs to store into a BST? I am not familiar with this concept nor can I find a suitable solution online

Comment: You can use std::map to insert your pair. map in STL are internally implemented as red black trees which are self balanced binary search trees. Refer the official docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map